# How can I get a nice progress indicator for video processing when working in a standalone kernel?

Tags: interface, video, version-12.1

When doing video processing, for example exporting an mp4, in the FE, I get a nice progress indicator with various estimates.  How can I get one in the standalone kernel?

Answer (score 13):

Easy! Just set `` Progress`$ConsoleSupport=True ``.  You can set this in your init.m and have it always on.

Now, the usual word of warning about undocumented functionality: it may change or break in the future, erase your hard-drive, or cause a global pandemic.  Use with appropriate caution.

Why did we hide such an awesome feature behind a flag?  Because we didn't feel it was ready.  It's probably in pretty decent shape on Unix-like systems (i.e., OSX & Linux).  We know it has issues on some Windows terminals.  And the "Windowed kernel", if you're one of the hearty souls who even knows what that is, is really bad.  So we'd really like to know about your experiences, especially on Windows.  So feel free to reply with comments about how it works for you.  If you have access to redmine and you encounter bad behavior, please report it there and CC me.  Try to include as much information about your OS and terminal emulator to help us test it ourselves.  Thanks!